# Не линкуется динамическая библиотека из смеси C и ASM

Tags: linux, c, ассемблер, gcc, библиотеки

Ошибка `/usr/bin/ld: func.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol 'tab' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC`, в любом случае. gcc 9.2.1

> func.asm, as:

```
.global func
.text
func:
lea tab+8(%rip), %rax
mov (%rax), %rax
ret

0000 488D0500 000000    lea tab+8(%rip), %rax
0007 488B00             mov (%rax), %rax
000a C3                 ret
```

> func.asm, nasm:

```
default rel
extern tab
global func
section .text
func:
lea rax, [tab+8]
mov rax, [rax]
ret

00000000 488D05(08000000)        lea rax, [tab+8]
00000007 488B00                  mov rax, [rax]
0000000A C3                      ret
```

> lib.c:

```
#include <stdint.h>
uint64_t tab[4] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
//uint64_t func();
uint64_t lib()
{
    return -1;//func();
}
```

> exe.c:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
uint64_t lib();
int main()
{
    printf("%lx\n", lib());
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
as --64 -o func.o func.asm
nasm -f elf64 func.asm
gcc -fPIC -c lib.c
gcc -shared -o lib.so lib.o func.o
gcc exe.c -L. -l:lib.so -o exe
```

// Исправил ошибки и добавил саму программу, без ассемблерной функции работает.
// Такой код работает, только это неправильно как-то. Должно быть 7 байт rip + offset, или на Linux не получится так?

```
0000 488B0500 000000    mov tab@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax
0007 488B4008           mov 8(%rax), %rax
000b C3                 ret
```

Comment: Добавьте флаг `-no-pie`.

Comment: @eanmos это не то что надо, появляются по 2 копии всего. у меня не получается саму библиотеку .so сделать

Answer (score 4):

> func.asm:

```
default rel
extern tab
global func
section .text
func:
lea rax, [tab+8]
mov rax, [rax]
ret
```

> lib.c:

```
#include <stdint.h>
__attribute__((visibility("hidden"))) uint64_t tab[4] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
uint64_t func();
uint64_t lib()
{
    return func();
}
```

> The precondition when writing 64-bit assembly is that the symbol must be "local" to the library (i.e. not global)

Comment: я проверил, у меня получилось. вот откуда вы узнали, дайте ссылку на источник пожалуйста!

Comment: а чем вариант с `GOTPCREL` в GAS'е не понравился?

Comment: @Fat-Zer в nasm-е такое тоже есть, [lib wrt ..gotpcrel], читает (mov) адрес в got адрес символа, к нему не получается например прибавить что-то или использовать как есть. xverizex: источники где-то тут mindfruit.co.uk или там agner.org

Comment: для справки, в GAS'е `lea tab@GOTPCREL+8(%rip), %rax` работает нормально (правда ни какой документации по этому поводу я найти не смог)... т.е на уровне elf ни каких препятствий к этому нет и всё упирается в синтаксис `nasm`'а...

Comment: @Fat-Zer это будет адрес следующий за tab, то есть неизвестно что

Comment: @J.Doe, да, ты прав... поигрался немножко — как я написал не работает (да и вообще бессмысленную белиберду означает)... в принципе логично, что нужно два раза разыменовывать адрес: сначала придётся одним `mov`'ом загрузить адрес символа из таблицы, а уж потом его модифицировать... как-то не подумал об этом сначала...